# How to receive emails from AWS SES using email client such as MS Outlook?

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, web-hosting, amazon-ses

I have an issue with AWS SES that it does not support inbound emails for ap-southeast (Sydney) region, therefore I'm unable to use WorkMail nor their solution using S3 + SNS + Lambda. Is there any a way that I can use different email hosting from different provider without deleting my MX and TXT records within Route53, something like redirect? If there is which email hosting provider that can support this which then I can use client email MS Outlook? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own solution as below:

- I chose the email hosting service from Zoho (free version as there is only me, you can upgrade to paid version any time, its quite cheap though.)
- I then setup the MX and TXT (including SPF and DKIM) records by using the ones provided by Zoho and added to Route53. Remember you have to delete the existing MX as well as TXT records if there is any.
- Once I've done the first 2 steps, I could setup my own email accounts such as support@mydomain.com, sales@mydomain.com, etc within the Zoho Control Panel.
- Now I can check incoming emails for those custom email accounts using Zoho web email portal or Zoho Android app. Note: with free version, Zoho does not allow IMAP or POP access which means you can't sync emails into email clients such as MS Outlook, however this is already good for me.